# how to extract values from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array which I want to extract the values using the [extract](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) php function but for some reason it's not working for me.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 45
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 18
        )

)
```

and this is the output I would like to see

```
$pid = 5;
$quantity = 1;
$price = 45;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a simple [foreach loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)?

```
$my_array = array(
    5 => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 45.00,
    ),
    7 => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 18.00,
    ),
);

foreach($my_array as $pid => $data) {
    $pid; // 5, 7
    $data['quantity']; // 1, 1
    $data['price']; // 45.00, 18.00
}
```

Comment: i want to insert the values into the db straight i have tried your method and its still not working for me this is what i did '
            $my_array = array(
    5 => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 45.00,
    ),
    7 => array(
        'quantity' => 1,
        'price' => 18.00,
    ),
);
foreach($my_array as $pid => $data) {
    $pid; // 5, 7
    $data['quantity']; // 1, 1
    $data['price']; 
 $data1=$data['quantity'];
 $data2=$data['price'];
 $sq="INSERT INTO order_detail(orderid, productid, quantity,price) VALUES ('1','$pid','$data1,$data2')";
 $res=mysql_query($sq);
}'

Comment: okkkay i think i get it now . the error was from my table naming thank u very much